# MS Appcenter ceasing support of Codepush for Cordova apps end March 2022. Is react-native a viable alternative?

Tags: react-native, cordova, visual-studio-app-center, code-push

We have two apps (one Android, one iOS) used by thousands of clients, which are built in Cordova.

We update the content (very regularly!) using Appcenter's Codepush plugin, but this is being retired at the end of March.

I believe that reactive-native Codepush support will continue.

Is it feasible to convert (or build from scratch) our apps in React-Native given that the content is many pages of a web site, extracted from a CMS and added to the Cordova app.

I have a tight deadline and am looking for a solution that will allow us to update our apps content quickly without having to republish the apps to the app stores each time we amend the pages.

ps I have little knowledge of React-Native as yet, but have seen comments that the 'Expo' framework may help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my Cross-platform developing knowledge best choice can be React Native , and it also works perfectly fine with App center as we used with some of our apps .

For transfering , some parts can be used , but some part needs to be totally recoded which wont take that much time according to your app functionality!
if you provide more detail i will be able to give you a better estimation and tools need to be used!

P.S. ***do not prefer Expo for Production if you will develop your app in a customizable way.***

Comment: Thanks, Amir.Essentially, our app is a web site downloaded and built as a cordova app. We use AppCenter for
Codepush to send updates to the html/css/javascript - the web site is updated in our cms, and we simply download the html/css/js to the cordova app folder and then call codepush CLI.

We also use AppCenter analytics to monitor page hits.

Could this be converted to React Native so that we still update by simoly downloadinf new html etc?
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: some parts will be usable , but coding with react native is fast and easy to maintenance , if we already have the website , we can open up a WebView and show the website , it will be ready in one day if we use this , otherwise according to the app's pages it will be different but again it wont take that much time @YesGenesisCamel

Comment: AmirThat sounds fantastic - that's how we do it in Cordova - the web page changes so we just copy the new html etc over the previous and use Codepush to send it out. Sounds like we can do something siilar with React Native.

Do you have any links to documentation/tutorials I can use to get started as quickly as possible?

Comment: you can directly use https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview this package , it the most active WebView package for RN ,
if you find the answer and comments useful you can vote up and accept this answer!
@YesGenesisCamel

Comment: Thank you, will investigate.

One last question - the webview access local html (/css/js) files - ie that form part of the app so they can be viewed when the device is not connected to the internet?

Comment: you can store them on the mobile device , and get them whenever you want @YesGenesisCamel
AsyncStorgae